# without using templates post data into database using only views file

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views, django-3.0

I want to post data into database directly by writing views in django without using templates. In model class i am using four fields such as (eno,ename,esal,eadd). For these fields i wanna post data into database directly only with the help of using views.

```
This is my model class  :

 class Employee(models.Model):
       eno = models.IntegerField()
       ename = models.CharField(max_length=20)
       esal = models.FloatField()
       eadd = models.TextField(max_length=40)  

This is my view.py file:

def emp(request):

   eno = request.POST[1289],
   ename = request.POST['siddarth'],
   esal = request.POST[20190.24],
   eadd = request.POST['india'],
   save_data = Employee.objects.create(eno=eno,ename=ename,esal=esal,eadd=eadd)
   save_data.save()
   return JsonResponse(save_data)
```

For that using view.py file directly i want to post data into database for model class fields and return response as JsonResponse.

Comment: "Is this possible in Django?" => well yes of course - all of what Django sees is a HTTP request, how it was built is irrelevant. "Above code snippet of views.py is not working" => "not working" is a totally useless description of a problem. Please read [ask] and [mcve] and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to *construct* an *object* of a `JsonResponse`. Furthermore you should remove the trailing commas (`,`) from the lines where you obtain the elements, since otherwise you wrap the value in a singleton tuple. The keys do not seem to make much sense either, since the keys look like *values*, and not keys.

We can thus fix the view to:

```
def emp(request):
    # no trailing commas
    eno = request.POST['eno']
    ename = request.POST['ename']
    esal = request.POST['esal']
    eadd = request.POST['eadd']
   save_data = Employee.objects.create(eno=eno,ename=ename,esal=esal,eadd=eadd)
   return JsonResponse({})
```

the keys of the `request.POST` might be different, depending on how you pass the data to the view.

Comment: That is fine.But i want post data

Comment: can you please help me @willem

Comment: @user98: well this view is capable to handle POST requests with data. The entries should be `eno`, `ename`, `esal`, and `eadd`...

Comment: can you please provide the example